# Microsoft Translator Error: Error retrieving translation

Tags: android, microsoft-translator

I've been trying make a translator application and I have set up everything accordingly. But still I get this particular error and been trying to solve it for a while.

```
package mobi.the404.appointed;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TranslateActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    private TextView textViewReceived;
    private TextView textViewTranslatedText;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private Button buttonTTranslate;
    private Button buttonTBack;
    private String selectedAp;
    private DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_translate);
        Translate.setClientId("ID");
        Translate.setClientSecret("SECRET");

        this.setTitle("Translate Appointment");
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {
            selectedAp = intent.getExtras().getString("selectedAp");
        }

        textViewReceived = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRecieved);
        textViewTranslatedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTranslatedText);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        buttonTBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTBack);
        buttonTTranslate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTTranslate);
        try {
            loadDetails();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        buttonTBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(TranslateActivity.this, AppointedActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                try {
                    this.finalize();
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        buttonTTranslate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    textViewTranslatedText.setText(translate(textViewReceived.getText().toString(), spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadDetails() throws Exception {
        db.open();
        Cursor item = db.getRecord(selectedAp);
        textViewReceived.append(item.getString(3));
        db.close();


        List<String> listLangs = new ArrayList<>();

        listLangs.add("Arabic");
        listLangs.add("Dutch");
        listLangs.add("German");
        listLangs.add("French");
        listLangs.add("Greek");
        listLangs.add("Hindi");
        listLangs.add("Italian");
        listLangs.add("Portuguese");
        listLangs.add("Thai");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listLangs);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    public String translate(String text, String lang) throws Exception {
        String translatedText = "";

        Language send = null;
        if(lang == "Arabic"){
            send = Language.ARABIC;
        } if(lang == "Dutch"){
            send = Language.DUTCH;
        } if(lang == "German"){
            send = Language.GERMAN;
        } if(lang == "French"){
            send = Language.FRENCH;
        } if(lang == "Greek"){
            send = Language.GREEK;
        } if(lang == "Hindi"){
            send = Language.HINDI;
        } if(lang == "Italian"){
            send = Language.ITALIAN;
        } if(lang == "Portuguese"){
            send = Language.PORTUGUESE;
        } if(lang == "Thai"){
            send = Language.THAI;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        translatedText = Translate.execute(text, send);
        return translatedText;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_translate, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And the error given out is this;

```
04-03 14:51:41.721  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ java.lang.Exception: [microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation : null
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveString(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:202)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:61)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:76)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at mobi.the404.appointed.TranslateActivity.translate(TranslateActivity.java:129)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at mobi.the404.appointed.TranslateActivity$2.onClick(TranslateActivity.java:73)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
04-03 14:51:41.726  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:367)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:295)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.getToken(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:133)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveResponse(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:160)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveString(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:199)
04-03 14:51:41.736  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
04-03 14:52:45.296  23897-23897/mobi.the404.appointed V/ActivityThread﹕ updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2c2786f6 token=android.os.BinderProxy@3379767a {mobi.the404.appointed/mobi.the404.appointed.TranslateActivity}} show : true
```

The application doesn't crash but the error is given. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I have given the permission for internet access in the manifest.

Thank you.ID

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that starting from `API 11` network calls are prohibited on the main thread, because otherwise main thread (UI thread) will be blocked waiting for response. If you take a look on the stacktrace you'll find, that when you call the following line at your click handler:

```
textViewTranslatedText.setText(translate(textViewReceived.getText().toString(), spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
```

The network call will be performed by the `API` you are using at the following line:

```
Translate.execute(text, send);
```

To avoid this exception you should call `Translate.execute` in async way. The most simple approach is to use `AsyncTask` if this network request doesn't take much time:

```
private static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Request, Void, String>{

    private WeakReference<TextView> translatedView;

    public MyAsyncTask(TextView translatedView) {
        this.translatedView = new WeakReference<TextView>(translatedView);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Request... params) {
        Request req = params[0];
        String translatedText = Translate.execute(req.getText(), req.getLanguage());
        return translatedText;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        TextView output = translatedView.get();
        if (output != null){
            output.setText(s);
        }
    }
}

private static class Request {
    private String text;
    private Language language;

    public Request(Language language, String text) {
        this.language = language;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Language getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(Language language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

However, there are also another approaches on how to do async operations, like using `IntentService`, creating `HandlerThread`, etc. Solution depends on your needs and requirements. You can read some information here http://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/

Answer (score 0):

This line in the log is the most important one:

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

So every time you use function that calls `Translate.execute`, create a new Thread:

```
new Thread(){
    public void run() {

        // ...
        translate(...);
        // ...

    }
}.start();
```

Comment: this is not a complete solution, because you are ignoring `translate` method return value. And if you get it, you should update UI, this cannot be done from background thread, but can be achieved using `runOnUiThread`, for example.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is more complete. My answer was just meant to be a *hint* that points in the right direction, I didn't want to rewrite his code. Anyway, I upvoted your answer :)